# Should I keep a value in the child association AND parent to avoid an extra query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a `Book`, which `has_many` `Photos`. When a user visits `/books/1` I want to display each of the book's photos in a gallery, but on the index page (`/books`) I only want to display one photo for each book. Note that I've added a column to the `Photos` table called `hero_image` which will contain a boolean value.

Out of a book's 50 photos, only 1 will ever be a `hero_image`. In order to get all of the hero images for the index page, would it not be more efficient to simple include a column on the `Book` table such as `hero_image` that contains the same value (`image-url`) as the `Photo` that is a hero_image? Doing so would save me an extra query to the database which would look up `Photos` based on the `hero_image` field and the `id` of the books being displayed.

Another important consideration is that I frequently update every `Photo` through a rake task, so if I was to include an `after_update` callback that updates a `Photo's` parent `if hero_image_changed?` (using [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)) then that would also be somewhat expensive (there are a LOT of photos and each of them would trigger the aforementioned callback)

Comment: This is called "denormalization" and yes, it is frequently used as an optimization technique (although I haven't seen it done yet with files/urls). Now that you know the keyword, you can read more about its pros and cons. and decide for yourself, whether you need to do it in this case or not.

Comment: A `Book` which `has_many :photos` could also `has_one :principal_photo` with option `conditions: { principal: true }, class_name: 'Photo'` (this implies `Photo` has a Boolean column `principal`, it could also rely on a (int) `position` column combined with an order). Then you could simple eager-load the `principal_image` relation when rendering the index of Books. This is a good middle-ground because caching can be a (callback) nightmare

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answers. I'm using Rails 5 which has deprecated `conditions`, therefore I used this instead: `has_one :hero_image, -> { where hero_image: true }, class_name: "Photo"`. @MrYoshiji can you please provide some code for how to eager load like you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a simple `has_one` defining the `principal_photo` among the related `photos`:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_one :principal_photo, -> { where(principal: true) }, class_name: 'Photo'
```

Eager Loading:

```
@books = Book.where(id: 1..999).includes(:principal_photo)
```

This code allows you to eager-load only the most relevant image and not all `photos` from a `Book` scope. **This will produce only 2 SQL requests**, one for retrieving the `Book` records and another one to retrieve their related `Photo` record defined as `principal`. This will save you from the pain of caching data and the callback hell behind it.